# bash how to create query string by checking args

Tags: bash

I'm trying to navigate to a twitch game channel via bash by creating my own command: twitch -game league of legends and producing the URL: https://twitch.tv/directory/game/league%20of%20legends but the code I've written is adding %20 to the last arg which I don't want:

```
function twitch() {

        if [[ $1 == -name ]]; then
        xdg-open https://twitch.tv/$2
        elif [[ $1 == -game ]]; then
                query=''
                args_length=$#
                for i in "${@:2}"
                do

                        if [[ i == ${@: -1} ]];then
                                echo $i
                        else
                        query+=$i%20
                        fi
                done
                echo $args_length $query
                xdg-open https://twitch.tv/directory/game/$query

        else
                xdg-open https://twitch.tv
        fi
}
```

Also, the query is printing https://twitch.tv/directory/game/league%20of%20legends but I'm directed to https://twitch.tv/directory/game/league of legends without the %20 I tried to add, any ideas?

Comment: `/game/league%20of%20legends` and `/game/league of legends` are exactly the same thing.  Almost all servers today accept either one.

Comment: `name=$(echo ${@:2} | sed "s/ /%20/g")` does it in one line.

Comment: Or do it all in bash, with `name=${*:2}; name=${name// /%20}`